# How to make Divs that don't fit on the screen stay on the same line, instead of going to the next row?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a width of 100%, and it has few columns (divs) inside. When we resize, the divs that don't fit, automatically do down, to the next row. How can I make them stay, and have a horizontal scroll on it??

```css
.col {
  float:left;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
  <div class="col">Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 </div>
  <div class="col">Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 </div>
</div>
```

Something like [THIS](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-a-resizing-menu-bar/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to add your working code to your question, please read this on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-askved=0ahUKEwjY88S0jMzJAhWDcRQKHdzuAa4QFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AFQjCNEDXp3Jt0aiEKFPFI03PFSjhs3gAw&sig2=Z7zAupFGKOoiAbjUgczi8A

Comment: [HERE'S THE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vhpr5mjk/1/)

Comment: decrease the width of your window, you'll see, the parentDivs that don't fit, they go to the new line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that you are using `float` for the internal `div`s.

You can use `display:table-cell` instead. This style force them to "stay in the line", as you can see in the above snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
  white-space:nowrap;  
  overflow-x:auto;
}

.col {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<h3>Longer</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
  <div class="col">Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 </div>
  <div class="col">Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 </div>
</div>
<hr />
<h3>Shorter</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I can't put margin on it!

Comment: That's true. Why do you need to set `margin` to each `div`? Set the `margin` on the `.wrapper`.

Comment: Righ, that's what I did actually! Thank you!